# How to use object's size() method instead of size() method in DefaultGroovyMethods?

Tags: groovy

Calling the `size()` method on a `java.util.List` delegates to `DefaultGroovyMethods.size(Iterable self)`. Is it possible to force directly calling the object's `size()` method?

Background:
Using other versions of groovy than `localGroovy()` in the Gradle build script leads to weird conflicts. In order to support Gradle version 2.0 in my plugin I need to be compatible with the runtime of `Groovy 2.3.2`, which doesn't have `DefaultGroovyMethods.size(Iterable self)`

Comment: Looks it is not related to `gradle` as tagged.

Comment: Shouldn't the end result be the same?

Comment: `DefaultGroovyMethods.size(Iterable self)` was introduced with groovy v 2.3.8, so it's not available in groovy 2.3.2: it fails with `NoSuchMethodException`

Comment: You're calling `DefaultGroovyMethods.size` directly?  `list.size()` should work whichever version of Groovy you're using...

Comment: No, I'm not, but if I compile it with groovy 2.3.8 the bytecode seems to reference this method

Comment: Normally you would just compile with groovy v2.3.2, but that leads to problems with gradle, so I figured this would be the simpler solution (if possible).
Currently I work around the problem by calling guava's `Iterables.size()`, but I though this should be possible with groovy directly...

Comment: Should I mention I'm using the `@CompileStatic` annotation?

Comment: Related links: [how do methods in DefaultGroovyMethods get applied?](https://marc.info/?l=groovy-user&m=134669275832513&w=2), [Override a method from DefaultGroovyMethods](https://user.groovy.codehaus.narkive.com/Hnix5kF9/groovy-user-override-a-method-from-defaultgroovymethods), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56401713,