# Prevent GroovyDefaultMethods join() from shadowing join() method of Java class?

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to use a Java library in Groovy, but Groovy is overriding one of the methods name `join` with its own method.

The following code fails:

```
%%classpath add mvn
tech.tablesaw tablesaw-core 0.32.6
tech.tablesaw tablesaw-beakerx 0.32.6
com.jimmoores quandl-tablesaw 2.0.0

%import com.jimmoores.quandl.*
%import com.jimmoores.quandl.tablesaw.*
%import tech.tablesaw.api.*

// display Tablesaw tables with BeakerX table display widget
tech.tablesaw.beakerx.TablesawDisplayer.register()

TableSawQuandlSession session = TableSawQuandlSession.create();
Table table1 = session.getDataSet(DataSetRequest.Builder.of("FRED/BCNSDODNS").build());
table1.column("Value").setName("Corporate Credit");
Table table2 = session.getDataSet(DataSetRequest.Builder.of("FRED/CMDEBT").build());
table2.column("Value").setName("Household Credit");
Table result = table1.join("Date").inner(table2, "Date");
```

The error is:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.inner() is applicable for argument types: (tech.tablesaw.api.Table, java.lang.String)

This is strange `Table.join(String)` returns a `DataFrameJoiner`: https://static.javadoc.io/tech.tablesaw/tablesaw-core/0.32.6/tech/tablesaw/api/Table.html#join-java.lang.String...-

I think what's happening is that `Table` is an `Iterable<Row>` so maybe Groovy is picking up [its own join method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html).

Where it gets really strange is that it works if I switch the Tablesaw version from `0.32.6` to `0.24.9` even though [`Table` also implements `Iterable<Row>` in that version](https://github.com/jtablesaw/tablesaw/blob/v0.24.9/core/src/main/java/tech/tablesaw/api/Table.java#L59)

Any idea how I can force Groovy to use the `join` method from the Tablesaw library instead of its own `join` method?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646135

Comment: Also consider asking on the Groovy users mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run into this problem because the prototype of the `Table.join()` method is the following:

```
public DataFrameJoiner join(String... columnNames)
```

<sup>Source: https://static.javadoc.io/tech.tablesaw/tablesaw-core/0.32.6/tech/tablesaw/api/Table.html#join-java.lang.String...-</sup>

You have already noticed that Groovy enhances `Iterable<T>` class with its `join()` method, but its prototype is the following:

```
public String join(String separator)
```

<sup>Source: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#join(java.lang.String)</sup>

This is why in the case of the following:

```
table1.join("Date").inner(table2, "Date");
```

Groovy resolves `Iterable<T>.join(String separator)` instead of the method from the `Table` class. It worked fine with the version 0.24.9 only because it was providing a method with the following prototype:

```
public DataFrameJoiner join(String columnName)
```

<sup>Source: https://static.javadoc.io/tech.tablesaw/tablesaw-core/0.24.9/tech/tablesaw/api/Table.html#join-java.lang.String-</sup>

So in this case, `Table.join(String columnName)` was overriding a method `Iterable<T>.join(String separator)`.

---

### The solution

You can solve this problem by making a call with an explicit `String[]` parameter information, so Groovy picks the correct method right away.

```
table1.join(["Date"] as String[]).inner(table2, "Date")
```

It would work without any explicit parameter type information if you pass two strings to make Groovy pick the varargs method.

```
table1.join("Date", "Something").inner(table2, "Date")
```

However, in case of a single string argument, you need to make an explicit parameter choice because of the two overloading methods definition.

Answer (score 1):

As per the other answer, this special case can be solved by using explicit typing in the method call. Here is just some more background information on the general topic of GroovyDefaultMethod overriding.

The documentation on this is scarce. Some old email threads relate to these methods coming from [DefaultGroovyMethods](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/1212b292c34804e3f14af2fbda5daaa85037a039/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L5957):

- [how do methods in DefaultGroovyMethods get applied?](https://marc.info/?l=groovy-user&m=134669275832513&w=2)

  > so when we create the ArrayList meta class, we inspect the 
  >   ArrayList class, grab all the methods from it and make our meta methods 
  >   out of it. Then we get the DGM methods list and apply all the methods in 
  >   their **depending on inheritance**..."

  This may explain why you get different results with different Tablesaw versions, depending on the exact inheritance details from `Iterable`.
- [Override a method from DefaultGroovyMethods](https://user.groovy.codehaus.narkive.com/Hnix5kF9/groovy-user-override-a-method-from-defaultgroovymethods)

  > If you want to do it for the duration of the script, you can use the
  >   per-instance metaClass to do:
  >
  > ```
  >  this.metaClass.println = { Object value ->
  >       System.out.println "woo $value"
  >  }
  > ```

From that I believe you can modify the Metaclass of `Table` to use the method you want to use. Since application of DefaultGroovyMethods also depends in inheritance details, you might also try subclassing Table.

The [metaprogramming docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.1/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html) might also help.

Comment: No need for using metaprogramming in this case. This is just a corner case where `join(String separator)` method gets overloaded with `join(String... columnNames)` so in case of a single parameter you need to make parameter type explicit if you want to pick the overloaded version that uses varargs.

Comment: Please leave the answer :-) I found the additional information very helpful! And answers allow for more formatting than comments